# Why is there such a difference in speed between Clojure's loop and iterate methods

Tags: clojure, loops

I have a question about why there is such a difference in speed between the loop method and the iterate method in clojure. I followed the tutorial in http://www.learningclojure.com/2010/02/clojure-dojo-2-what-about-numbers-that.html and defined two square-root methods using the Heron method:

```
(defn avg [& nums] (/ (apply + nums) (count nums)))
(defn abs [x] (if (< x 0) (- x) x))
(defn close [a b] (-> a (- b) abs (< 1e-10) ) )

(defn sqrt [num]
  (loop [guess 1]
    (if (close num (* guess guess))
        guess
     (recur (avg guess (/ num guess)))
)))

(time (dotimes [n 10000] (sqrt 10))) ;;"Elapsed time: 1169.502 msecs"


;; Calculation using the iterate method
(defn sqrt2 [number]
    (first (filter #(close number (* % %)) 
        (iterate #(avg % (/ number %)) 1.0))))

(time (dotimes [n 10000] (sqrt2 10))) ;;"Elapsed time: 184.119 msecs"
```

There is about a x10 increase in speed between the two methods and I'm wondering what is happening below the surface to cause the two to be so pronouced?

Comment: i assume first `sqrt2` is a typo?  also, you need to repeat timings several times to get useful results (the jvm takes time to optimize).  it doesn't change the fact that one is slower, but it does change the numbers significantly.

Comment: Yep... fixed it now... so 10000 times isn't enough?

Comment: i don't know for sure, but it seems to be time-based - like, it gets faster over the first second or so.  did you try repeating it and looking at the output from time()?

Comment: 10000 times is usually enough, but you need to run the whole thing multiple times since your first run or two will include the cost of initial interpretation + JIT compilation overhead. Typically I just re-run the the `(time ...)` command four or five times until the timings stablilize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your results are surprising: normally loop/recur is the fastest construct in Clojure for looping.

I suspect that the JVM JIT has worked out a clever optimisation for the iterate method, but not for the loop/recur version. It's surprising how often this happens when you use clean functional code in Clojure: it seems to be very amenable to optimisation.

Note that you can get a substantial speedup in both versions by explicitly using doubles:

```
(set! *unchecked-math* true)

(defn sqrt [num]
  (loop [guess (double 1)]
    (if (close num (* guess guess))
      guess
      (recur (double (avg guess (/ num guess)))))))

(time (dotimes [n 10000] (sqrt 10)))
=> "Elapsed time: 25.347291 msecs"


(defn sqrt2 [number]
  (let [number (double number)]
    (first (filter #(close number (* % %)) 
      (iterate #(avg % (/ number %)) 1.0)))))

(time (dotimes [n 10000] (sqrt 10)))
=> "Elapsed time: 32.939526 msecs"
```

As expected, the loop/recur version now has a slight edge. Results are for Clojure 1.3

Comment: Definitely speeds up the loop/recur function... what does the *unchecked-math* flag do?

Comment: it turns off overflow checking for primitive operations. useful for a small amount of extra speed, the downside is that you won't get an exception if an overflow happens so you need to be a bit more careful.

Comment: Fantastic! it definitely speeds up the loop/recur function... i got 38.0ms for sqrt and 67.3ms sqrt2... =)